UEFI consumes >25% main memory
I just installed Ubuntu Linux 24 on a brand new Thinkpad T14s Gen 5.
According to the original order, the BIOS and system data, the notebook has 16GB main memory.
However, after UEFI boot, when running the memory test installed by Ubuntu or when checking after OS boot the information by top, free or /proc, only 11.6 GB are available. So it seems that UEFI boot reserves more than a quarter of the memory.
On an older notebook and on a server, the difference between installed memory and memory usable by Linux is negligible.
Any ideas, where this memory might have gone and whether this is to be expected?

Edit: Output of free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        11880440     1807412     8696304       55108     1707520    10073028
Swap:        4194300           0     4194300


Linux keeps apps in RAM as cache. You often reuse apps, so then faster access. Those are released, if space needed for newer app. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743649/new-16gb-of-ram-installed-yet-i-see-15-3-on-my-system-why?noredirect=1#comment1106622_743649 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/184217/why-most-people-recommend-to-reduce-swappiness-to-10-20/184221#184221

@oldfred Thanks for your comment, in particular for the link. Commands like top, free and the info below \proc account for that and show the available memory, with and without cached apps. All these programs, as well as memtest before even booting into Linux (but after UEFI boot), consistently show the total available memory as 11.6 GB. This seems to be the amount visible to and usable by Linux. The full 16GB are only available before UEFI boot. The BIOS and its memory check show this amount, so it seems that UEFI boot uses the difference for some unknown purpose.

the missing RAM is probably used as VRAM by the GPU

Can you post the entire exact output of free?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Done.

@GabrielePigozzo Thanks for the hint, this seems to be the solution. The laptop has an integrated graphics card, which according to some Lenovo web page (and maybe in general) means that the VRAM is part of the main memory. The commands on https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-linux-vga-video-card-ram/, like glxinfo tell that the VRAM is 4GB, which basically fills the gap. Do you want to write an answer?
